# SpagoBI KPI engine : set a default KPI to show without clicking

Tags: javascript, jsp, spagobi, kpi

Using the **SpagoBI KPI engine**, i was wondering how i could specify a default KPI to be shown without clicking , as the default view is a blank frame with the message "No KPI associated" . So, i spent some time to have a look at the KPI.JSP located at **[/WEB-INF/jsp/engines/kpi/custom/kpi.jsp](https://github.com/svn2github/SpagoBI-V4x/blob/master/SpagoBIProject/web-content/WEB-INF/jsp/engines/kpi/custom/kpi.jsp)**, i found that there i s a Javascript Function which pass a grid and an accordion to a class : **Sbi.kpi.KpiGUILayout**, and in this class a default settings are defined ! i tried to modify it, but i didn't succeed. I need just to know which function is called after the mouse click event !
Can you please help me with that, because it's very important to have a direct access to a detail, specially if we have just one KPI node !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had found a workaround to achieve that, simply i made a trigger click event just after the rendering of my KPI's tree in  **/WEB-INF/jsp/engines/kpi/custom/kpi.jsp** :

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
            var item = new Sbi.kpi.KpiGUILayout(config);
            var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout:'fit',               
                items:[item],
            });


            //@Hassan : trigger a click event
            var l = document.getElementById('extdd-2');
            l.click();

            });

});
```

I believe that's not a correct way to handle that, but it work !